# Decimal Rounding in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, rounding

I have code that is taking information from the database to insert into a list. One piece of data that I'm taking will be used for price. (I set its type to decimal in SQL Server), for example: " 1,80".

But when I select it, my decimal variable returns the value 2 !

I want to know if there are a simple way to make decimal not automatically round numbers.

This is the code:

```
public decimal preco { get; set; } 

while (dr.Read())
{
    clsCaProd oProd = new clsCaProd();
    oProd.cod = dr.GetInt32(0);
    oProd.preco = dr.GetDecimal(1); // Here returns "2" instead of "1,80"
    oProd.info = dr.GetString(2);
    oProd.categ = dr.GetString(3);
    oProd.nome = dr.GetString(4);

    lProd.Add(oProd);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of what you're trying to pull from the database before this code is executed? Is it 1.80? Otherwise, I don't understand how using GetDecimal rounds a number.

Comment: You need to specify the precision and scale when you set the column type to `decimal` - e.g. `decimal(19,4)`

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the sql that is run to get this data row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a column as `decimal`, the default "scale" is zero. You need to specify the [precision and scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).

Try [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17319):

```
declare @d1 decimal = 1.80
declare @d2 decimal(19,4) = 1.80

select @d1, @d2;
```

Results:

```
2        1.8000
```

Comment: I've declared the column as decimal(10,2) and now it fits well for me !